# What is Socialcam and how do I disable it?

Tags: facebook

More and more frequently, I am seeing posts tagged "Socialcam" pop up on my Facebook feed. When I click these links (which often feature gaping shark jaws, large snakes, ambiguous ladyskin, or other provocative imagery), I am asked to open the videos through the Socialcam app. But I don't want to! In fact, I don't want to see these Socialcam posts on my newsfeed ever!

Is there any way to keep these posts from popping up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What is Socialcam:** Socialcam is a feed of user-generated videos.  Just by clicking on a Socialcam link in Facebook and accepting their app, every Socialcam video you watch from then on is shared to your Facebook friends automatically. In your case, you just see the content from your friends who use the Socialcam app. The content is questionable, the titles of the videos are often salacious, and the images it posts in your timeline can be downright embarrassing.

**How to disable Socialcam posts:** In any of the Socialcam posts, click on the little down arrow on the right, and select "Hide all by Socialcam". This will disable all Socialcam posts. You can also block the app from your settings.

Answer (score 3):

As for what is it, [it’s a video sharing app for iPhone and Android](http://socialcam.com/).

> Socialcam is a smartphone application that makes it easy to share videos with friends.

[Source](http://socialcam.com/frequently_asked_questions).

Regarding your second question, I don’t know if you have to do something specific, but I assume you could hide the posts just like any other post made by an app. Or, like phwd mentions in the comment below, you could block it just like any other Facebook app.

Comment: Or just block it like any other Facebook application. That should remove it from the feed as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get rid of this staff just click on the little down arrow on the right, and select "Hide all by Socialcam". App sending it also can be blocked from your settings.